# MySQL JSON column loses decimal precision when JSON object inserted as a string literal

Tags: java, mysql, json, jdbc

I am trying to insert a JSON document into a MySQL JSON column and have noticed that decimal precision is lost in.

```
{"value": 212765.700000000010000}
```

Gets reduced to

```
{"value": 212765.7}
```

I've tried inserting directly via MySQL Workbench and I've noticed different behavior depending on how I do.  For example:

```
insert into json_test values ('{"value": 212765.700000000010000}');
```

Produces the same result.. however the following works:

```
insert into json_test values (json_object('value', 212765.700000000010000));
```

I can generate the insert statement dynamically building the JSON object with the json_* function calls which works for single inserts.. but I'm using JDBC batch updates which requires the SQL to have a consistent number of parameters (our JSON documents vary in structure, so this does not work) or to explicitly set the values without using bind parameters which is obviously a security risk.

Any way around this?

Comment: Can you store your json object using {"value": "212765.70000000100000"}? Doing so would force the value to be stored as a String meaning the precision would not be changed.

Comment: We've considered this but ideally is our last resort.  Hoping someone has found a better workaround.

Comment: You know what, I think that is the expected behavior because [at this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) they say MySQL store the numbers as integers and double, then try to store `212765.700000000010000` in a double variable (I tested in java) then print it, the result will be the same as MySQL, it think that is a double problem, don't ask me why **json_object** works

Comment: You probably know that if you create a double column without specify the precision then MySQL will do rounding just like is occurring in your case with double variables in JSON

Comment: I think it's better to define a lower precision(`212765.70`) or store it as a long(`21276570` you will need to let the precision fixed as well) or string as suggested (`"212765.700000000010000"`). I saw some financial software like kmymoney saving double values as integers (just removing the point) at the database, in some cases it could be better

Comment: @deFreitas - You're right that the troublesome value is being converted to DOUBLE, resulting in lost precision. However, MySQL does support DECIMAL in JSON data, at least internally, which is why `json_object` can produce the correct result. See [here](https://pastebin.com/TQcLHXgK), particularly line 19.

Comment: I think [this is a related reported bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83954)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments to the question, this appears to be an issue with the way MySQL parses JSON literals containing non-integer numeric values for which DOUBLE is not the best data type. If you want to supply the JSON as a string literal to speed up the batch insert process then one possible workaround would be to INSERT the numeric values as JSON strings and then UPDATE the rows after the batch insert is complete:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE json_test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, jv JSON);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)
```

Insert the numeric values as strings ...

```
mysql> INSERT INTO json_test (id, jv) VALUES (1, '{"value": "212765.700000000010000"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO json_test (id, jv) VALUES (2, '{"whatever": "foo"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO json_test (id, jv) VALUES (3, '{"value": "212765.700000000010000", "whatever": "bar"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM json_test;
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | jv                                                     |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"value": "212765.700000000010000"}                    |
|  2 | {"whatever": "foo"}                                    |
|  3 | {"value": "212765.700000000010000", "whatever": "bar"} |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

... and then UPDATE the rows to CAST the values to DECIMAL:

```
mysql> UPDATE json_test SET jv = JSON_REPLACE(jv, '$.value', CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(jv, '$.value') AS DECIMAL(21,15))) WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(jv, '$.value')) = 'STRING';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM json_test;
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | jv                                                   |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"value": 212765.700000000010000}                    |
|  2 | {"whatever": "foo"}                                  |
|  3 | {"value": 212765.700000000010000, "whatever": "bar"} |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(jv, '$.value')) AS jt FROM json_test WHERE id=1;
+---------+
| jt      |
+---------+
| DECIMAL |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```